# How to run a thread after JVM exits in java?

Tags: java, windows

I am writing an application where it has two threads:
[1] main 
[2] threadX

main thread is command line program and starts an application(mongodb) in background and then exits.

threadX is the Server part of my application which requires to be active as long as the application(mongodb) is running.

main takes two arguments: start and stop.

On start: it starts -> start mongod and threadX.

On stop: it starts -> kills mongod and (should)stops threadX.

But even after setting threadX as daemon it stops after main thread exits.

Proof:

```
public class Index {
public static void main(String [] args) {
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger("Index logging");
    try {
        FileHandler logfile = new FileHandler("test.log");
        logfile.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
        log.addHandler(logfile);

    } catch (SecurityException | IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Thread daemonThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                   log.log(Level.INFO,"Try block executed");
                    Thread.sleep(1000l);
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    t.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void finalize() {
            log.log(Level.INFO,"Finalize method called");
        }
    };
    daemonThread.setDaemon(true);
    daemonThread.start();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(3500l);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        //NO-OP
    }
}
}
```

Output:

```
Apr 08, 2017 2:30:54 PM num.Index$1 run
INFO: Try block executed
Apr 08, 2017 2:30:55 PM num.Index$1 run
INFO: Try block executed
Apr 08, 2017 2:30:56 PM num.Index$1 run
INFO: Try block executed
Apr 08, 2017 2:30:57 PM num.Index$1 run
INFO: Try block executed
```

As you can see it does not continues to write logs after main exits

What i want is a thread that can be started in background and continue to run even when main thread exits and that thread can be stopped after i restart my app. Just like console applications which starts processes in background and quit leaving console available to user. The user can then use command to stop that background process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Daemon threads *do* exit after the `main` method exits - if you do not want your thread to exit you should *not* make it a daemon thread.

Remove the line

```
daemonThread.setDaemon(true);
```

or change it to

```
daemonThread.setDaemon(false);
```

From the Javadoc of the setDaemon method:

> The Java Virtual Machine exits when the only threads running ***are*** all
>   **daemon** threads.

Comment: I want the app to work as(for instance) the commands in linux. say i type "nohup gedit &". The shells then starts the app in background and then the  user can use terminal without having to stop/close the application. I want to the same kind of thing.

Comment: Run Java from a shell script with "nohup java ... &"

Answer (score 0):

Create a User Thread and not a Daemon Thread. Why do you need to set the Thread as Daemon?

JVM will not terminate a User Thread and it will wait for it to finish before exiting unlike Daemon Thread.

Hope this Helps

Comment: The app  should not accept any input from user after typing command(say app start), and should exit from console. If i do use User thread, the app occupies the console (does not allow the user to enter any command), and  I dont want that.

Comment: You can Start a process in background..Fall back to OS to do that for you...For Linux use ' <command> & ' and for windows there are couple of ways. a VB Script or a Windows Service will let you do it.
Hope this helps...google on this you'll find many ways how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If I get right at what you're trying to accomplish: you want a program to control mongodb. Separate invocations of the program may have diffrent commands as their command line arguments.

In the case of "start": your app should start mongodb as a separate process so it can exit right after mongodb started. You wont need thread to keep mongodb running.

In the case of "stop": You'll have to connect to the mongodb process and tell it to shut down gracefully, wait for it to end and end your own program.

Comment: yes, and my server-side thread is constantly sending messages to all of its clients, thus after starting mongod instance there is no need for the app to keep occupying console